# AspNetCore Health Checks UI Reporting Wrongly

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, pipeline, health-check

I've been having a little issue implementing **AspNetCore.HealthChecks.UI** correctly. I have two endpoints that run health checks using the "live" and "ready" as tags. Both endpoints work work as expected but after implementing the HealthChecksUI, The health check results displayed is always "**Unhealthy
An error occurred while sending the request**." even though the endpoint returns "Healthy" from postman. Please see screenshots and relevant code snippets and configurations.

[image]
[image]

**AppSettings Configuration**

```
"HealthChecksUI": {
    "HealthChecks": [
      {
        "Name": "Crowd Funding App",
        "Uri": "http://localhost:5001/healthui"
      }
    ],
    "EvaluationTimeinSeconds": 10,
    "MinimumSecondsBetweenFailureNotifications": 60
  }
```

In the Configure function of the startup class, I have the following code.

[image]

Comment: In your `Crowd Funding App` Health checks setting, aren't you getting data from `http://localhost:5001/healthui`? Didn't you want to perform that to either something like `http://localhost:5001/health/ready` or `http://localhost:5001/health/live`?

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: The code looks good, but something in the configuration annoys me. Your 5001 port seems to be served via https. Could it simply be that you are trying to consume the non-secure version of your website with the wrong port ? Try to replace the URL in your settings with `https://localhost:5001/healthui`.

Comment: @ArnaudLeclerc Thank you so much. Https was the issue. Works perfectly fine now.